# how to migrate swagger document 1.2 to 2.0?

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

What is the easiest way to make swagger version 2.0 documents using existing node.js APIs?

Currently I am using node-swagger-express npm. The generates swagger documents's version is 1.2.

Except using swagger-converter in command line, what is the easiest way to migrate swagger 1.2 to swagger 2.0?

I installed npm swagger, and it saids that swagger-editor@2.10.5 requires higher node version (>= 5.8.0)